# Why my variable appear empty in Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I made this short script to monitor and, if needed, restart the printer spooler on a few servers

```
$c = Get-Credential
$servers = 'FQDN1', 'FQDN2', 'FQDN3'
foreach ($s in $servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -Credential $c {$j = (Get-PrintJob -PrinterName 'Test Printer').count
        Write-Host "On computer $s there are $j print jobs"
        If ($j -gt 5){
            Write-Host "About to restart the printer spooler on $s"
            Restart-Service 'Spooler'
        }
    } # end of invoke-command
} # end of foreach
```

What I don't understand is why the `Write-Host` does not write the server name (`$s`), but it writes instead the number of jobs (`$j`).

I guess it has something to do with the variable being in the remote session but not in the local one. 
But I can't really understand what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you have to *pass the variable to the scriptblock* in order to access it.

To do that, you have to define a `Param()` section at the start of your scriptblock and pass the argument (server) using the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
$c = Get-Credential
$servers = 'FQDN1', 'FQDN2', 'FQDN3'
foreach ($s in $servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -Credential $c -ScriptBlock {
        Param($s)
        $j = (Get-PrintJob -PrinterName 'Test Printer').count
        Write-Host "On computer $s there are $j print jobs"
        If ($j -gt 5){
            Write-Host "About to restart the printer spooler on $s"
            Restart-Service 'Spooler'
        }
    }  -ArgumentList $s # end of invoke-command
} # end of foreach
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for the explanation. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

As of PowerShell 3.0, you can refer to a local variable in a remote session scriptblock with the `$using:` prefix:

```
foreach ($s in $servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -Credential $c {
        Write-Host "On computer $using:s now"
    } # end of invoke-command
} # end of foreach
```

See the [`about_Remote_Variables` helpfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149005.aspx) for more information

Comment: nice one, didn't knew that +1

Comment: Even better. Thank you very much.